# How do i unlink different parts of a 3d model?

Tags: mesh, objects, interface, import

[image: Selected a part of the 3d model]

[image: Tried to change the color of the selected part but the entire model got affected]

Could someone tell me how to unlink parts of a 3d model to make changes on the separate parts? The model here was from an imported fbx file . I tried separating the highlighted part with the 'P' hotkey for separation. When I try to change the color of the selected part, the whole object gets its color changed and I've not been able to figure out how to isolate each part and work on them separately. I'm pretty much a beginner so if anyone has any links to some tutorials or articles on how to do separation of different parts of a 3d model from an imported fbx file I would be super grateful.

Comment: @Robert's answer is a common 'grammar' all over Blender.. referring to all sorts of shared data..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have successfully separated the objects, but they share a single material. This is indicated by the number of users next to the material name.

In order to create an individual copy of the material for the active object, click on the button with the number.

[image: Make single-user copy]

Comment: Thanks, Robert. That worked  :)